# Convert datagridview data with Image from SQL Db into a PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, datagridview, itext

I'm a newbie to creating C# desktop apps..

Can anyone help me out? How can I export / convert my datagridview data with image column which is filtered from my SQL database into a PDF file in C#?

**Note**: it's a desktop app && must want to convert each image from datagridview column with fixed size also..

Thanks in advance <3